# Scapy Dot11ReassoReq

Tags: python, scapy

What is scapy's Dot11ReassoReq, and what does it do? It does sound ideal for my purposes: I want to make a tool that (among other things) searches for hidden APs. My code so far:

```
def tickle(*args,**kwargs):
    packs1=[]
    packs2=[]
    for client in appinstance.sframe.interior.clients.copy():
        pkt=Dot11(addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",addr2=client,addr3=client)/\
             Dot11Deauth()
        packs1.append(pkt)
    for client in appinstance.sframe.interior.clients.copy():
        pkt=Dot11(addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",addr2=client,addr3=client)/\
             Dot11ReassoReq(current_AP=client)
        packs2.append(pkt)
    packs1*=32
    shuffle(packs1)
    packs2*=32
    shuffle(packs2)
    packs=packs1+packs2
    appinstance.stopprogressbar()
    appinstance.startprogressbardet(len(packs),
                                       "Trying to expose hidden AP's")
    for pkt in packs:
        send(pkt,verbose=0)
        appinstance.progressbar.step()
    appinstance.stopprogressbar()
```

However, Wireshark reports that these ReassoReq packets are invalid. Why, and what packets should I use to get a client to reconnect after a Deauth packet?

Answer (score 2):

Huh. It was clearly discribed at http://people.cs.nctu.edu.tw/~yctseng/WirelessNet2010-02-nctu/ieee802-11-management.ppt, slide 38. Dot11Disas() is probably the way to go.